# Javascript right shift a negative number

Tags: javascript

Here is the snippet:

```
var i = 101;
console.log('101: ' +  i.toString(2));
console.log('101 >> 1: ' + (i >> 1).toString(2));

var l = -101;
console.log('-101: ' + l.toString(2));
console.log('-101 >> 1: ' + (l >> 1).toString(2));'
```

Output:

```
"101: 1100101"
"101 >> 1: 110010"
"-101: -1100101"
"-101 >> 1: -110011"
```

Why `-101 >> 1` is `-110011` instead of  `-110010` ?

---

Update: the book **Professional javaScript for Web Developers** explains how js stores a negative number:

1. get the binary representation of the absolute value of the negative number
2. replace 0s with 1s and 1s with 0s
3. add 1 to the result of step 2

So in my case `-101 >> 1`, we first convert -101 to its binary representation:

1. The binary representation of Math.abs(-101) is:

   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0101
2. invert the 0s and 1s:

   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1010
3. add 1 to the end:

   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1011
4. Now, shift it to the right by 1:

   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 1101

The binary above should be the correct result of `-101 >> 1`, but when logging a negative number's binary representation, Javascript simply puts a negative sign in front of the binary representation of the positive number:

```
var x = 15;
console.log(x.toString(2)); // output: 1111

var y = -15;
console.log(y.toString(2)); // output: -1111
```

For our example, this means that when logging the result of `-101 >> 1`, JS will output `minus sign` + `the binary representation of the positive number`. But the positive number is not `101 >> 1` because `101 >> 1` gives you:

```
(101 >> 1).toString(2);  // output: 110010
(-101 >> 1).toString(2); // output: -110011, not -110010!
```

To get the correct result, we have to reverse the aforementioned step 1-3:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 1101   // this is the result we get from step 4
```

Reverse step 3 by subtracting 1, we get:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 1100
```

Reverse step 2 by invert 0s and 1s:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0011
```

Reverse step 1 by converting this binary to integer:

```
parseInt(110011, 2); // output: 51
```

Finally, when JS logs the result of `-101 >> 1`, it will be `minus sign` + `the binary representation of 51` which is:

```
(51).toString(2);        // output:  110011
(-101 >> 1).toString(2); // output: -110011
```

Comment: `>>` (Sign-propagating right shift) - **This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Copies of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. Since the new leftmost bit has the same value as the previous leftmost bit, the sign bit (the leftmost bit) does not change. Hence the name "sign-propagating".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that negative numbers are stored as a 2s-complement. For simplicity, let's say it's a 1-byte signed integer, then -101 would be stored as

```
1 0000 0000 (256)
- 0110 0101 (101)
= 1001 1011 (155 if it were unsigned, -101 in signed)
```

When bit-shifting a negative number, you right-pad with `1`s instead of `0`s (otherwise you'd lose the sign bit), so the result is:

```
  1001 1011
       >> 1
= 1100 1101
```

That is 205 if it were an unsigned integer. Then 2s-complement it back to solve `256 - x = 205` => `x = 51`

Ta-da? :D

Comment: This is incomplete. You need to explain that `i` is actually a float, but the operands of `>>` are converted to signed 32-bit ints, and the result is converted back to a float.

Comment: I read a book and updated the question, do you think my explanation is correct?