# Why does -3 >> 1 equal -2?

Tags: javascript

In JS, we have the following situation:

`<<` operator:

```
3 << 1  // 6
5 << 1  // 10
7 << 1  // 14
-3 << 1 // -6
-5 << 1 // -10
-7 << 1 // -14
```

`>>` operator:

```
3 >> 1  // 1
5 >> 1  // 2
7 >> 1  // 3
-3 >> 1 // -2
-5 >> 1 // -3
-7 >> 1 // -4
```

As you can see, for the `<<` operator, and for values less than 2**32, we have `abs(X << Y) === abs(-X << Y)`.

Why doesn't this keep true for the `>>` operator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022052/javascript-right-shift-a-negative-number Potentially relevant reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are rotating the binary representation of those numbers. And the negative numbers are stored as *[2's complement binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)*

So (using just 8-bits for illustration purposes):

`-3 = 11111101`

Which if you rotate with `>>` which is *sign propagating* you will get:

`11111110 = -2`

Because the *sign propagating* shift copies the sign bit to the left-most bit.

With the positive numbers it's easier:

`3 = 00000011`

After shifting with `>>` (since it's positive, you are shifting in zeros)

`00000001 = 1`

Comment: aren't numbers stored as 64-bit floating-point? As far as I know floating-point doesn't use 2's complement for negative numbers.

Comment: Yes, JS store numbers as floating point numbers, however binary operations doesn’t make much sense in such numbers, so JS casts them to the integers, perform binary operation, and cast back.

Answer (score 0):

It's because minus has [greater precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) than shift operator.

So, `-3 >> 1` will run as `(-3) >> (1)` but not as `-(3 >> 1)`.